# How do I calculate amplitude and phase angle of fft() output from real-valued input?

Tags: r, fft

I have 24 samples from a real-valued signal. I perform the `fft()` function on the sample and get the complex output. I want to obtain the amplitude and phase angle of each of the non-redundant harmonics. I know my calculation must account for aliasing since I have real-valued data. How do I:

(1) convert from the two-sided to a one-sided Fourier transform,

I've heard several things here. For example, do I multiply the first 12 harmonics (i.e., 2nd through 13th elements of `fft()` output) by two and drop the rest of the harmonics (i.e., keep 1st through 13th elements of `fft()` output)?

(2) calculate the amplitude of the one-sided Fourier transform,

I know I can use the `Mod()` function, but when do I do this? Before or after I convert from two- to one-sided?

(3) calculate the phase angle of the one-sided Fourier transform.

I know I can use the `atan()` function on the ratio of imaginary to real parts of the `fft()` output, but again, when do I do this? Before or after two- to one-sided conversion? Also, what if `atan` is undefined?

Thanks.

Comment: At the moment this feels to me more like a math question than a programming question, and so runs the risk of being considered Off Topic.

Comment: @joran: it's probably better suited to http://dsp.stackexchange.com but we do still get a lot of FFT-related questions on SO and they seem to be tolerated so long as there is at least a token practical programming aspect to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input is real the output of the FFT will be symmetric about N / 2 so you can just look at the first N / 2 bins and scale the magnitude by a factor of 2. For the phase you ideally need an atan2 function which takes the real and imaginary components as separate arguments and returns a 4 quadrant result.

Comment: Well, technically the first N/2+1 bins.

Comment: @Owen: yes, although the last one is Nyquist and of somewhat dubious usefulness.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Before I check the answer and give you the glorious rep you so richly deserve, I have points of clarification: (a) by scale by a factor of 2, you mean multiply the n/2 (or n/2 + 1) components by two, yes? (b) So the Nyquist is of dubious usefulness...please clarify. What should I do with the Nyquist? Not multiply it by two? (c) Is the scale factor of two why in the formula to compute the variance of a given component, I am told to divide the square of the magnitude by two? Thanks again.

Comment: (a) you can either multiply the real and imaginary components of each of the N / 2 bins by 2 or you can just multiply the *magnitude* by 2 - it amounts to the same thing, (b) in the general case your anti-aliassing filter will be severely attenuating the Nyquist component - it's up to you whether it's useful to include it in your spectrum or not, (c) we'd need to see the formula for variance that you are using

Comment: variance = (amplitude^2)/2 per http://met.jometeo.gov.jo/pls/portal/docs/PAGE/WEATHER/TAB4100/DR%20QASEM2.PDF page 5

Comment: OK - no they have already taken care of the `x 2` from symmetry in (3) and (4) above - I'm not sure where the `/ 2` for variance comes from but it looks like you still need it

Comment: Ah, yes. LOL. Feel like an idiot for not seeing (3) and (4). Thanks, man. I wish that in the prose, they would not say "every harmonic" or "all harmonics" when discussing how to calculate proportion of variance explained, because that makes it sound like they are using frequencies above the Nyquist, which of course they are not doing (unless you count anti-aliasing via scale factor usage of Nyquist frequencies above N/2).