# Are real and imaginary parts of fft ouput correlated?

Tags: r, math, fft

I want to use model-based clustering to classify 1,225 time series (24 periods each). I have decomposed these time series using the fast Fourier transform and selected the harmonics that explain at least a threshold percentage of time series variance for all time series in the sample. I want to do model-based clustering on the real and imaginary parts for each transform element of a give time series because it would potentially save me from having to account for temporal autocorrelation in model awed clustering across periods of a time series. I know that each complex element of the fast Fourier transform is independent from other elements, but I do not know if the imaginary and real parts of the output for a given output element are independent. I would like to know because if they were, it would allow me to maintain the default assumption of the Mclust package in R for model-based clustering that the variables analyzed have a multivariate Gaussian distribution.

NOTE: The full FFT is not used as I have discarded the elements at negative frequencies and converted from a two-sided to a one-sided spectrum by multiplying frequencies 1 to Nyquist by two per advice here: [How do I calculate amplitude and phase angle of fft() output from real-valued input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264530/how-do-i-calculate-amplitude-and-phase-angle-of-fft-output-from-real-valued-in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real part and the imaginary part are orthogonal (due to the sin(x) and cos(x) functions being orthogonal).  This characteristic is essential to how an FFT works.

Per [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html):

> A Fourier series is an expansion of a periodic function  in terms of
>   an infinite sum of sines and cosines. Fourier series make use of the
>   orthogonality relationships of the sine and cosine functions.

The FFT is essentially a change of basis.  That says nothing about the data itself which may or may not contain correlations between the real and imaginary parts.

With respect to the edited question, "How do I calculate amplitude and phase angle of fft() output from real-valued input?."  The way to convert the real component and imaginary components to magnitude and phase angle is `magnitude = (real_part ** 2 + imaginary_part ** 2) ** 0.5` and `angle=arctan2(imaginary_part, real_part)`.  It is the same as a [rectangular-to-polar conversion](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_2/chpt_2/5.html).

Comment: Good answer - I would just add though that clustering is far more likely to be successful/meaningful with phase/magnitude rather than real/imaginary components

Comment: But aren't phase and magnitude necessarily dependent on one another because they are functions of the real and imaginary parts? Aftr clustering it would be straightforward to calculate them

Comment: This question appears to conflate "independent" (in the sense of statistical distributions) with "orthogonal" (in the sense of spaces of functions).  As such the answer makes a mathematically correct but irrelevant statement and arrives at an incorrect answer to the problem as stated, as explained in comments in a cross-post at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/are-real-and-imaginary-components-of-frequency-element-of-fft-correlated.  However, it turns out that in this problem the full FFT is not used (although that is not disclosed).

Comment: @whuber Again, orthogonal vectors are linearly independent: Proof: http://www.ualberta.ca/MATH/gauss/fcm/LinAlg/InRn/SbVctrSpc/OrthgnlLnrlyIndpndnt.htm

Comment: *Linear independence* has nothing to do with *statistical independence*. @whuber's statement is correct.

Comment: I have posted a full explanation at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/19013/919 and added some commentary to differentiate the concepts of independence, which is the focus of this question, and orthogonality, which is not.