# Finding the frequency from Data

Tags: signals, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I have an input Data from a device for example like this:

```
12,85,365,145,23
13,84,364,144,21
11,86,366,143,24
14,83,363,146,22
```

somehow I should to intreprete this Datas. At the first I did FFT on these Datas and I could find the amplitude:

```
50.000000 338.000000 1458.000000 578.000000 90.000000
1.414214   1.414214    1.414214   2.828427  1.414214
4.000000   4.000000    4.000000   2.000000  4.000000
1.414214   1.414214    1.414214   2.828427  1.414214
```

now I would like to find the frequenty, for example this amplitude:1.414214 has blabla Herz frequency. How can I do that with this infos? Is it possible or I need mor Infos

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask: Do you know what your FFT algorithm does? Usually, it does not use a time axis and you have to calculate the frequencies using your sampling frequency (gives you your Nyquist frequency). The amount of data can either yield the frequency resolution or increase your SNR, depending on how data are processed. The most basic algorithms do the first thing, though.

Comment: I didint get exactly what you mean, but I can imagin that these 4 rows of sampling data takse 4 seconds

Comment: OK, if 4 rows of data take 4 seconds, one row will take one second. Thus, you take 5 samples per second, which is 5Hz. Thus, your Nyquist frequency is 2.5Hz and your frequency axis will have 5 ticks starting at 0Hz up to 2.5Hz.
Note, that imagining does not give you a real time or frequency axis (;

Comment: Could you please explain me with my example? :/ sorry I am really new in this field

Comment: your frequency (x) axis according to your statements:

 0.   ,  0.625,  1.25 ,  1.875,  2.5  

I recommend some basic readup, that could start here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_frequency
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_fourier_transform

Comment: Thank you so much. and could you please say me too how can I find Nyquist frequency in my data?

Comment: Yes - its always the exact half of your sampling frequency.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_Frequency

Good luck with your data evaluation!

Comment: This exact question is asked so often here on SO I created a blog post to answer it in detail: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Comment: @BjornRoche Thanks, Its my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following similar question to get the foundation of fft.

[Reconstructing a signal from its discrete fourier transform in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323022/reconstructing-a-signal-from-its-discrete-fourier-transform-in-r/18347919#18347919)